# When is node_search() in the node module called?

Tags: 6, nodes

Someone has made changes to core, and specifically the `node_search()` function in the node module.

I'm not familiar with this function. What does it do, and under what circumstances is it being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`node_search()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_search/6) is the node module's implementation of [`hook_search()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_search/6), which:

> allows a module to perform searches on content it defines (custom node types, users, or comments, for example) when a site search is performed.

That hook is invoked from a [number of different places](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/invokes/hook_search/6).

At a guess I would say if someone was going to make changes to `node_search()` it would probably be for the 'search' operation (i.e. altering the results of the standard node search). That particular operation is invoked from [`search_data()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.module/function/search_data/6).

It might be worth having a look a regular copy of `node_search()` alongside your hacked copy to see if you can understand what the differences are, and whether you can revert the changes without breaking things (if that's what you need to do).

Comment: OK, so I don't know how many hours I have spent reading the API docs and I never noticed the "implements" or "invokes" sections on the hook pages...

Comment: @MPD I think they're fairly new; I can only remember seeing them in the last couple of months or so

Answer (score 1):

@Clive has the right answer, but I have a sidenote that is too involved for a comment.

The search interface in Drupal is one of the least changeable, as far as the hook system and theming system goes (compared to the rest of Drupal).  There are some modules for 6 that improve things ([Custom Search](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_search/6) and [Search Config](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search) are two), but they only help to an extent.  There is also the [Apache Solr Search Integration](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) project, which is probably the best long term solution if you can do Solr.

I have been in situations where Solr isn't an option, and the above mentioned modules don't do what the client needs.  In this case, the proper thing to do is take the standard [node_search](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_search/6) function and clone it into your own custom module, and then make modifications.  Once you have this going, it is just a matter of rewiring the search form(s) and your templates.  This works rather well, and you should consider this for your site as it makes applying updates a lot easier.